# Sharepoint Text Display and Radio button list coding

Tags: sharepoint, radiobuttonlist

How do I create a display of text, radio buttons and submit button in Visual Studio such that I can display my text to the user so that

1. The user cannot edit the text
2. The user's choice of radio button and the displayed question can be stored on clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

(1) Simple: set enabled="false" for the control

&

(2) Store the information from the radio button into a session variable on btn submit click, I'm pretty sure you can edit the string you save